# Deep link no longer works in Blazor webassembly using Azure AD authentication after update to .Net 8

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-webassembly

We implemented Azure AD in our Blazor webassembly app following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-microsoft-entra-id?view=aspnetcore-6.0
(article changed after introduction of MS Entra)

And deep linking worked out of the box. But now after we upgrade to .Net 8 and upgraded all related security packages the user is always redirected to the root of the application after login. The app.razor looks as follows:

```
   <CascadingAuthenticationState>
      <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
         <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
               <NotAuthorized>
                  @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true) {
                     <RedirectToLogin/>
                  }
                  else {
                     <p role="alert">@_localizer["Globaal.NietGeautoriseerd"]</p>
                  }
               </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"/>
         </Found>
         <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
               <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 50px;" role="alert">@_localizer["Globaal.PaginaNietGevonden"]</p>
            </LayoutView>
         </NotFound>
      </Router>
   </CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

and in the RedirectToLogin the returnUrl is set correctly:

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

@code {
   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
      Navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(Navigation.Uri)}");
   }
}
```

I can't figure out what has changed let alone how to solve it, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there now is a NavigateToLogin method :-/

```
  InteractiveRequestOptions requestOptions =
     new()
     {
        Interaction = InteractionType.SignIn,
        ReturnUrl = Navigation.Uri,
     };
  Navigation.NavigateToLogin("authentication/login", requestOptions);
```